# How to combine coefficients for multiple model fits into a single tidy table

Tags: r

I am new to R and was wondering if there was a way to add coefficients from different regression fits into a single tidy table?

Kind Regards,

Matt

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, there is. Details depend on the specific function your are using for fitting the model and for some types of models possibly even on the specific input.

Comment: Use `broom::tidy` on your models and you should be able to find a way to `rbind` (or `bind_rows`) them together.

Comment: package stargazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this if you only have a few models:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

mtcars %>% 
  glimpse()

mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

mod1_tidy <- tidy(mod1) %>% mutate(model = 1)
mod2_tidy <- tidy(mod2) %>% mutate(model = 2)

bind_rows(mod1_tidy, mod2_tidy)
```